# Recover git lfs storage

Tags: git, git-lfs

I started to use git lfs, but then I realized that there was a storage limit quota. Now I wanted to recover git lfs storage. I tried removing git lfs and deleting .gitattributes but it still shows in my account that I have half storage used out of 1 GB.

Is there any way to recover that space?

If I reinitalize the repo, I would like to maintain my commits history. How can I do that?

Thank you all for the support!

Comment: Whose git-lfs storage are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions in [Removing files from Git Large File Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage).

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a way, on Github, to remove what's in storage without [deleting the whole repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/deleting-a-repository) and recreating it. Follow the instructions for [mirroring a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository).